# Error : Could not create Java Virtual Machine when launching javaw - viewer

Tags: java, jvm

I'm launching `javaw -viewer` command through command prompt, I'm getting pop-up error message saying that,

> Error : Coud not create Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error : A fatal exception has occured. Program will exit.

but the remaining command are working fine.

like `java -version`

See the image for error: [image]

One more point I want to add, I'm running **jdk1.7** also in my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such command as `javaw -viewer`. Perhaps you meant `javaws -viewer`?

Comment: Silly mistake. Thank you